# Cloudflare Worker: TypeError: Cannot reconstruct a Request with a used body

Tags: javascript, typescript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have the following two functions described in my Cloudflare worker code. However, when I run the code and these functions get called I get a `TypeError: Cannot reconstruct a Request with a used body` -

```
async function getApiV2Token(env: Env): Promise<string> {
    let API_URL = await getApiUrl(env)
    let API_CLIENT_ID = await getApiClientId(env)
    let API_CLIENT_SECRET = await getApiClientSecret(env)

    let apiUrl = `${API_URL}/auth`
    let data = `client_id=${API_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${API_CLIENT_SECRET}`

    let response, responseJSON 

    try {
        response = await postData(apiUrl, data)
        responseJSON = await response.json()
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error: ${e}.`)
        return ""
    }
    return responseJSON.auth_token
}


async function postData(url: string, data: string): Promise<Response> {
    let request = new Request(url, {
        method : 'POST',
        body : data,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'cloudflare-worker',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        redirect : 'manual'
    })
    
    let cache = caches.default
    let cachedResponse = await cache.match(request.url)
    if (cachedResponse) {
        return cachedResponse
    }
    console.log("checked cache")

    let response = await fetch(request)

    console.log("Requested new token")

    let newResponseForExpiresIn = response.clone()
    let newResponseForExpiresInJSON = await newResponseForExpiresIn.json()
    let expires_in = newResponseForExpiresInJSON.expires_in
    let newResponseForHeader = response.clone()
    let newResponseToCache = new Response(newResponseForHeader.body, newResponseForHeader)
    newResponseToCache.headers.set('Cache-Control', `max-age=${expires_in - API_TOKEN_GRACE_PERIOD}`)
    cache.put(request.url, newResponseToCache)

    return response
}
```

The line it fails at is `let response = await fetch(request)` (found this because "checked cache" is logged but not "Requested new token".

Here's what I've tried -

1. `newRequest = request.clone()` and then fetching that instead.
2. creating an identical request with `new Request()` and then fetching that.
3. same as above but using `slice()` to copy `data`

I also looked at [Cloudflare Worker TypeError: One-time-use body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920957/cloudflare-worker-typeerror-one-time-use-body) but because I'm using the [Cloudflare Worker Modules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/migrating-to-module-workers/) I don't have access to `event`. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I logged `request.bodyUsed` before the offending line and it logs `false`

Comment: This is quite strange, from the code you provided this doesn't look like it should be happening as the request is clearly only consumed once. Can you write a fully self-contained test case on cloudflareworkers.com demonstrating the problem, and post the share link here?

Comment: I can certainly give it a shot sometime tomorrow. I also noticed that the request is clearly being used only once but thought `cache.match()` was somehow making a request.

Comment: @KentonVarda looks like I can't use the module format and typescript (which is what I am using for my project) in the sandbox you shared.

Comment: In your code you have `cache.match(request.url)`, which shouldn't use the request since you're only giving the URL. If you actually had `cache.match(request)`, then the behavior you are seeing would be expected. Yes, you will have to remove the type annotations and inline any imports in order to use the sandbox, but I wouldn't be able to debug something more than a couple dozen lines anyway... you may find the issue yourself in the process of narrowing down the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by constructing the request within fetch, not sure why.

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
    method : 'POST',
    body : data,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'cloudflare-worker',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted in your question is actually the exact code that leads to the problem? In particular if `cache.match(request.url)` was actually `cache.match(request)` in the original code, that would explain the issue...

Comment: I'm sure I was using `request.url`. There are other functions in the worker but the request was first constructed in the `postData()` so again, as you mentioned, it should not have been used. I was able to fix this though, thanks for your help!